# Stubbing and/or mocking a class in sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I've created a database wrapper for my application, shown below. To test it, I obviously would like to replace the actual database library. I could create a new class that mocks the `query` method and catch all input there, but using `sinon.js` seems more appropriate, but how would I use it?
Is the `mock` or `stub` features of `sinon.js` what I should be using?

```
wrapper = (function() {

  function wrapper() {}

  wrapper.db = require("database");

  wrapper.prototype.insertUser = function(doc) {
    return this.db.query("INSERT INTO USERS...");
  };

  return wrapper;

})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use both for that.

**Mock** have an expected ordered behavior that, if not followed correctly, is going to give you an error.

A **Stub** is a similar to a mock, but without the order, so you can call your methods the way you want.
In my experience you almost never need a mock.

Both of them will substitute your method for an empty method, or a closure if you pass one.
It would be something like this:

```
stub = sinon.stub(wrapper , 'insertUser ', function () { return true; });
```

Then you add the expect behavior to check if it did happened.

I like to use [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) with [Jasmine-Sinon](https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon) for checking the tests.

Comment: Oh. So It would be better to stub the `insertUser` method rather than the `this.db`-call that `insertUser` does?

Comment: Depends on what you are testing, but if you want to test if the insertUser is inserting in the DB that would be a integration test and no stubbing would save you from using the real logic with some in memory DB to "fake" a Oracle for example, if you want to test if the insertUser is called when needed then stubbing insertUser method could be a way of doing it...

Comment: As of 3.0 this would now be `stub = sinon.stub(wrapper , 'insertUser ').callsFake( function () { return true; });`

Comment: stub(obj, 'meth', fn) has been removed, see documentation

Answer (score 10):

First, I'd modify your class definition a bit (uppercase class name and fix db assignment):

```
var Wrapper = (function() {

  function Wrapper() {
    this.db = require("database");
  }

  Wrapper.prototype.insertUser = function(doc) {
    return this.db.query("INSERT INTO USERS...");
  };

  return Wrapper;

})();
```

To stub the whole class:

```
var WrapperStub = sinon.spy(function() {
  return sinon.createStubInstance(Wrapper);
});
```

`sinon.createStubInstance` will create an instance of Wrapper where every method is a stub. `sinon.spy` will allow us to spy the class instantiation.

So you could exercise it like this:

```
// verify instantiation
var wrapper = new WrapperStub();
expect(WrapperStub).to.have.been.calledWithNew;

// verify method stub
wrapper.insertUser.returns('data');
expect(wrapper.insertUser()).to.equal('data');
expect(wrapper.insertUser).to.have.been.calledOnce;
```

(assertions use [chai](http://chaijs.com/) and [sinon-chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai))

I said just "exercise it" because this code snippet is not an actual unit test. Instantiation and method calls will be made by your subject under test.

Now, if you want to mock a dependency injected by require() –such as `db = require('database')` in your example–, you could try a testing tool like either [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/automatic-mocking.html) (but not using sinon) or [sinonquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinonquire) which I created inspired by **Jest** but to use it with sinon plus your favorite testing tool (mine is **mocha**). Internally, **sinonquire** uses the same technique shown above of combining `sinon.spy`and `sinon.createStubInstance` to stub a class.

Comment: Updated links to Jest: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/jest-object.html#jestenableautomock