# Stub action2 helper on testing action2 controller routes response supertest

Tags: sails.js, sinon, supertest

I have a project on [Sails.js 1](https://sailsjs.com/)

I try to use TDD on development, so I've added route testing. To prevent real API call in helpers I've mocked them via **sinon**

So I can successfully pass tests with this code

#### action2 controller code

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Some action',


  description: '',


  inputs: {
    requiredParam: {
      example: 'some_value',
      required: true,
      type: 'string',
    }
  },


  exits: {
    someError: {
      description: 'Handles some error happens in controller',
      message: 'Some error handled in controller',
    }
  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    const someProcesses = await sails.helpers.someHelper(inputs.requiredParam);

    if (someProcesses === 'someError') {
      exits.someError(someProcesses);
    } else {
      exits.success(someProcesses);
    }

  }


};
```

#### Helper code

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Some helper',


  description: '',


  inputs: {
    requiredParam: {
      example: 'some_value',
      required: true,
      type: 'string',
    }
  },


  exits: {
    someError: {
      description: 'Just some error happens in workflow',
      message: 'Some error happens!',
    }
  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    // All done.
    return inputs.requiredParam === 'isError' ? exits.success('someError') : exits.success('someProcessedValue');

  }


};
```

#### test code

```
const request = require('supertest');
const {createSandbox} = require('sinon');

describe('GET /some-page/some-action', () => {
  before(() => {
    this.sandbox = createSandbox();
    this.sandbox.stub(sails.helpers, 'someHelper')
      .withArgs('some_value').returns('someProcessedValue')
      .withArgs('isError').returns('someError');
  });

  after(() => {
    this.sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should response OK', async () => {
    await request(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .get('/some-page/some-action')
      .query({requiredParam: 'some_value'})
      .expect(200);
  });

  it('should response with error', async () => {
    await request(sails.hooks.http.app)
      .get('/some-page/some-action')
      .query({requiredParam: 'isError'})
      .expect(500);
  });
});
```

Then I've read on [the official doc helper page](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers#?handling-exceptions) that we should use `exits` and `intercept` to correctly handle errors from helpers on **Sails.js 1**.

So I've rewritten my action2 and helper to its usage and got next

#### Action2 controller with action2 intercept handling

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Some action',


  description: '',


  inputs: {
    requiredParam: {
      example: 'some_value',
      required: true,
      type: 'string',
    }
  },


  exits: {
    someError: {
      description: 'Handles some error happens in controller',
      message: 'Some error handled in controller',
    }
  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    const someProcesses = await sails.helpers.someHelper(inputs.requiredParam)
      .intercept('someError', exits.someError);// Error happens here

    return exits.success(someProcesses);

  }


};
```

#### Helper with exit triggering

I noticed this is problematic to test action2 controllers with preventing real helpers calls, cause when we stub helper methods using we got an error on next chained call but without these calls we can't user recommended error handling.

While I haven't used chained machine methods (`tolerate`, `intercept` etc) all test passes successfully, but when I affect it, I got an error.

#### Error

> error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
>    TypeError: sails.helpers.someHelper(...).intercept is not a function

I've prepared [a repo on GitHub](https://github.com/pahan35/sails-v1-bug-test) if someone wants to try some idea.

#### Repo tags

1. **correct-test-result-without-chained-helper-methods** - tests without reverse
2. **broken-tests-with-chained-methods** - broken tests.

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109254/sails-js-mocha-supertest-sinon-how-to-stub-sails-js-controller-function) but it is for **Sails.js 0.12.14-**

Any idea how to avoid this problem? I will appreciate any answer.

Comment: Hi there, I don't know how to help here, but I was new to sails and was trying to create a clean db after each test file runs. Do you know how to set this up? I posted a question here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53638665/1828637 and here - https://github.com/ndabAP/vue-sails-example/issues/74

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, @Nick. I haven't found a solution for it for a month, and then I switched to another project without using sails.js