# How to stub static methods with sinon in ES6?

Tags: node.js, sinon, stub

```
var MyClassStub = sinon.createStubInstance(MyClass);
```

MyClassStub doesn't contain static methods. How to fix that?

Comment: `MyClassStub.__proto__ = MyClass`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072016/stubbing-a-class-method-with-sinon-js

Answer (score 47, accepted):

static method:

```
sinon.stub(YourClass, 'yourClassMethod').callsFake(() => {
  return {}
})
```

not static method:

```
sinon.stub(YourClass.prototype, 'yourClassMethod').callsFake(() => {
  return {}
})
```

Answer (score 10):

Using sinon version 3.1.0 I am able to mock (stub) private static variable using the code given below:

```
const YourClass = require('./lib/YourClass');
const mockStaticMethod = sinon.stub(YourClass, '_yourStaticMethod').returns('I am called');
```

The only thing that you have to remember that the first parameter in sinon.stub() method should be the class itself. It should not be object of that class like `const yourClassObject = new YourClass();`. The reason is that any object of the class won't let you access static methods.