# How to stub a module with sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, sinon

I need to stub hubspot module in order to test my apis.

I need to test this code:

```
const createCompany = async company => {
  const hubspotClient = new hubspot.Client({
    apiKey: HUBSPOT_KEY
  });

  //stuff
  const companyObj = {
    properties: {
      //my properties
    }
  };

  return await hubspotClient.crm.companies.basicApi.create(companyObj);
};
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072016/stubbing-a-class-method-with-sinon-js) They show how to stub a class and access a method through its instance, but in my case I have multiple properties like `.crm.companies.basicApi.create()`.

I tried doing:

```
getDataStub = sinon
  .stub(hubspot.Client.prototype, 'crm.companies.BasicApi.create')
  .resolves(fakeResponse);
```

But it doesn't work and it says `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property crm.companies.basicApi.create`.

Do you have any hint on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HubspotClient instance outside of `createCompany`. Then export that instance so in the test file you could stub methods of it.

```
const hubspotClient = new hubspot.Client({
    apiKey: HUBSPOT_KEY
  });
// ...
const createCompany = async company => {
    // ...
    return await hubspotClient.crm.companies.basicApi.create(companyObj);
}
// ...
stub(hubspotClient.crm.companies.basicApi, 'create');
```