# How to stub function that returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chai, sinon

I'm trying to stub a function using sinon. The function has the following signature

```
export function getIndexDocument(
    svc: MetaHTTPService | ServiceConfig
): MetaPromise<RepoResponseResult<IndexDocument>> {
```

Is this the right way to sub it

```
sandbox.stub(getIndexDocument).resolves({} as RepoResponseResult)
```

I tried that but it returns an error.

Here's how this function is called.

I have a class called AssetsController with the following functions

```
 public async exploreIndexDocument(): Promise<Asset | undefined> {      
    // it makes an HTTP request and returns a promise that resolves with the following info { repoId: "", assetId: "" }

     const {
            result: { assignedDirectories }
     } = await getIndexDocument(this.serviceConfig).catch(err => {
        throw new Error(`Bad repsonse`);
     });

     return {
        repoId: result.repoId;
        assetId: result.assetId
     }

}

public async function copyAsset(asset) {
   const res = await this.exploreIndexDocument();
   const repoId = res.repoId;
   return asset.copy(repoId);
}
```

I'm trying to test the function copyAsset, but it calls exploreIndexDocument which calls getIndexDocument. getIndexDocument is imported at the top of the file and lives in the module @ma/http.
getIndexDocument makes an HTTP request.

How can I test copyAsset given that it calls getIndexDocument which makes an HTTP request?

Comment: _"I tried that but it returns an error."_ What error? Also, what is `MetaPromise`?

Comment: MetaPromise is a Promise. I get the following error -- Property 'resolves' does not exist on type 'SinonStubbedInstance(svc: MetaHTTPService | ServiceConfig) => _IMetaPromise  "http://ns.meta.com/metacloud/rel/repository">, MetaResponseType>, any, unknown>>'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to the docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/), you can't stub an existing function.

You can:

```
// Create an anonymous sstub function
var stub = sinon.stub();

// Replaces object.method with a stub function. An exception is thrown
// if the property is not already a function.
var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method");

// Stubs all the object’s methods.
var stub = sinon.stub(obj);
```

What you can't do is stub just a function like:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(myFunctionHere);
```

This makes sense because if all you have is a reference to a function, then you can just create a new function to use instead, and then pass that into where ever your test needs it to go.

---

I think you just want:

```
const myStub = sandbox.stub().resolves({} as RepoResponseResult)
```

---

In your update it sounds like you want to put the stub on the `AssetsController` class. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072016/stubbing-a-class-method-with-sinon-js/45260191) for more info on that, but in this case I think you want:

```
const myStub = sandbox
  .stub(AssetsController.prototype, 'exploreIndexDocument')
  .resolves({} as RepoResponseResult)
```

Now anytime an instance of `AssetsController` calls its `exploreIndexDocument` method, the stub should be used instead.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZwIYDsAmAjCAPOAzKCEOAcgWBQhRICgaBjAGyQQTgEFWBTGBAYSoxCjRlyhwA3jTgy4YAK4ZGwenBYBPFKq7YwjaFwCS6HQBEI9eSC4oYACgCUALjgAFQiGAIuAHglwAdwALJBguADcxFwQhCgBzOABfAD5JaVkMqB55KBQ3Dy8uADoshAhGSLt-YNCIqNIYqHiSJId0mUSaTppkdCxsIpjFO05vXgFbYVEoIrBCGAgYdTAuABpSHT0DYzQzCysbGBIHEq4yirOqwJCwyKgXEjwICAwkKBbEhyA)

Comment: hi Alex, the issue is that the function that I'm testing called getIndexDocument which makes an HTTP request. I want to stub that function, but you say that I can't. What should I do instead?

Comment: Mocking strategies are heavily dependent on how you acquire a reference to the mocked thing, and how the mocked thing is used. Neither of those details are present in question, so I can't be of much help.

Comment: so I have a function copyAsset in the class AssetsController. It calls a function called exploreIndexDocument in the class AssetsController. That function calls getIndexDocument from another module. getIndexDocument makes an API call - essentially a get request to get a list of directories in a specific folder. I want to write a test for the function copyAsset; however, in order to do so, I have to stub the getIndexDocument function. But you are telling me that I cannot do that.

Comment: Add this info with code snippets showing how this function is imported and used to your original question, and I'll try help more.

Comment: ok I updated my question.

Comment: Answer updated! In general, mock the thing the function is on, not just the function. In this case, that's `AssetsController`.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I think most of your problems can be solved by revisiting your architecture. For example, instead of creating an explicit dependency on `getIndexDocument` within your `AssetController` class you can simply inject it in. This will allow you to swap implementations depending on the context.

```js
type IndexDocumentProvider = (svc: MetaHTTPService | ServiceConfig) => MetaPromise<RepoResponseResult<IndexDocument>>;

interface AssetControllerOptions {
  indexDocumentProvider: IndexDocumentProvider
}

class AssetController {
  private _getIndexDocument: IndexDocumentProvider;

  public constructor(options: AssetControllerOptions) {
    this._getIndexDocument = options.indexDocumentProvider;
  }
}
```

Then you can use `this._getIndexDocument` wherever and not worry about how to make the original implementation behave like you want in your tests. You can simply provide an implementation that does whatever you'd like.

```
describe('copyAsset', () => {
  it('fails on index document error.', () => {
    const controller = new AssetController({
      indexDocumentProvider: () => Promise.reject(new Error(':('));
    });
    ....
  });

  it('copies asset using repo id.', () => {
    const controller = new AssetController({
      indexDocumentProvider: () => Promise.resolve({ repoId: "420" })
    });
    ...
  });
});
```

You can obviously use `stubs` instead of just functions or whatever if you need something fancy.

Above we removed an explicit dependency to an implementation and instead replaced it with a contract that must be provided to the controller. The is typically called `Inversion of Control` and `Dependency Injection`