# stubbing an entire class for testing in sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

*Preamble: I've read lots of of SO and blog posts, but haven't seen anything that answers this particular question.  Maybe I'm just looking for the wrong thing...*

Suppose I'm developing a `WidgetManager` class that will operate on `Widget` objects.

How do I use sinon to test that WidgetManager is using the `Widget` API correctly without pulling in the whole `Widget` library?

Rationale: The tests for a WidgetManager should be decoupled from the Widget class.  Perhaps I haven't written Widget yet, or perhaps Widget is an external library.  Either way, I should be able to test that WidgetManager is using Widget's API correctly without creating real Widgets.

I know that sinon mocks can only work on existing classes, and as far as I can tell, sinon stubs also need the class to exist before it can be stubbed.

To make it concrete, how would I test that `Widget.create()` is getting called exactly once with a single argument 'name' in the following code?

#### code under test

```
// file: widget-manager.js

function WidgetManager() {
   this.widgets = []
}

WidgetManager.prototype.addWidget = function(name) {
    this.widgets.push(Widget.create(name));
}
```

#### testing code

```
// file: widget-manager-test.js

var WidgetManager = require('../lib/widget-manager.js')
var sinon = require('sinon');

describe('WidgetManager', function() {
  describe('#addWidget', function() {
    it('should call Widget.create with the correct name', function() {
      var widget_manager = new WidgetManager();
      // what goes here?
    });

    it('should push one widget onto the widgets list', function() {
      var widget_manager = new WidgetManager();
      // what setup goes here?
      widget_manager.addWidget('fred');
      expect(widget_manager.widgets.length).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

*Aside: Of course, I could define a `MockWidget` class for testing with the appropriate methods, but I'm more interested in really learning how to use sinon's spy / stub / mock facilities correctly.*

Comment: Looks like the case where `addWidget(widget: WidgetInstance)` is preferred over `addWidget(name: String)`. Is there anything that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: This seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819242/stubbing-and-or-mocking-a-class-in-sinon-js/33383157

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is really about dependency injection.

You want to test that `WidgetManager` is interacting with a *dependency* (`Widget`) in the expected way - and you want freedom to manipulate and interrogate that dependency. To do this, you need to inject a stub version of `Widget` at testing time.

Depending on how `WidgetManager` is created, there are several options for dependency injection.

A simple method is to allow the `Widget` dependency to be injected into the `WidgetManager` constructor:

```
// file: widget-manager.js

function WidgetManager(Widget) {
   this.Widget = Widget;
   this.widgets = [];
}

WidgetManager.prototype.addWidget = function(name) {
    this.widgets.push(this.Widget.create(name));
}
```

And then in your test you simply pass a stubbed `Widget` to the `WidgetManager` under test:

```
it('should call Widget.create with the correct name', function() {
  var stubbedWidget = {
      create: sinon.stub()
  }
  var widget_manager = new WidgetManager(stubbedWidget);
  widget_manager.addWidget('fred');
  expect(stubbedWidget.create.calledOnce);
  expect(stubbedWidget.create.args[0] === 'fred');
});
```

You can modify the behaviour of your stub depending on the needs of a particular test. For example, to test that the widget list length increments after widget creation, you can simply return an object from your stubbed `create()` method:

```
  var stubbedWidget = {
      create: sinon.stub().returns({})
  }
```

This allows you to have full control over the dependency, without having to mock or stub all methods, and lets you test the interaction with its API.

There are also options like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) or [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) which give more powerful options for overriding dependencies at test time. The most suitable option is down to implementation and preference - but in all cases you are simply aiming to replace a given dependency at testing time.

Comment: A combination of proxyquire with sinon makes testing miracles.

Answer (score 3):

Your `addWidget` method does 2 things:

- "converts" a string to a `Widget` instance;
- adds that instance to internal storage.

I suggest you change `addWidget` signature to accept instance directly, instead of a name, and move out creation some other place. Will make testing easier:

```
Manager.prototype.addWidget = function (widget) {
  this.widgets.push(widget);
}

// no stubs needed for testing:
const manager = new Manager();
const widget = {};

manager.addWidget(widget);
assert.deepStrictEquals(manager.widgets, [widget]);
```

---

After that, you'll need a way of creating widgets by name, which should be pretty straight-forward to test as well:

```
// Maybe this belongs to other place, not necessarily Manager class…
Manager.createWidget = function (name) {
  return new Widget(name);
}

assert(Manager.createWidget('calendar') instanceof Widget);
```

Comment: These are helpful insights and worth an upvote.  But `return new Widget(name)` presumes I have access to the Widget class or that I've stubbed it somehow, which if you read the OP, is an incorrect presumption.

Comment: When testing adding, you don't need access to `Widget`. When testing creation of `Widget`s, I don't really see a point of using stubs. If you want to make `Manager` independent of `Widget`s, move creation somewhere else.

Comment: Agreed!  I nearly provided another example, using `fs` as the dependent package, and wanted to test that (for example) `fs.readFileSync()` gets called by my code.  What would you do in that case?  (I can extend my example if that would help...)